# How to create tables in Athena with radon's JSON results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Can json's keys be variable when Athena creates tables?

{***"E:\temp\ds-api\functions\src\api\XXX\XXXX.py":*** [{"type": "function", "rank": "B", "lineno": 46, "col_offset": 0, "complexity": 10, "endline": 120, "name": "__lambda_handler", "closures": []}, {"type": "function", "rank": "A", "lineno": 20, "col_offset": 0, "complexity": 3, "endline": 43, "name": "lambda_handler", "closures": []}], "E:\temp\ds-api\functions\src\api\chklist\chg_chklist.py": [{"type": "function", "rank": "C", "lineno": 50, "col_offset": 0, "complexity": 14, "endline": 110, "name": "__lambda_handler", "closures": []}, ...

Comment: Could you be more specific as to what your desired outcome is, how you are trying to achieve it and any steps you have taken so far to answer?

Comment: After I generate JSON file with radon, I want to express it with Athena and QuickSight of aws, but when I create table structure with Athena, I don't know how to create table structure, because the file name in JSON file is changeable, I don't know how to create table. The JSON file generated by radon is as I wrote above.

Comment: you probably want to process the json a little so that the file name in the data is a key instead of a value, then the schema should be more consistent and useable in Athena/Quicksight